# How to add line break to factor level in forest_model

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-forestplot

I am using the forest_model function from {forestmodel} package. The names of the levels in my grouping factor are quite long and makes it impossible to see other data in the forest_model because the "group" column is so wide. How can I wrap the text of a factor level?

Can I add something to the panel parameter? Adjusting the width of the column containing the Group levels did not work...

Here is my code for the panels

```
mypanels <- list(
  list(width = 0.001, display = ~level, hjust = 0.5, 
heading = "Group" {{{{CAN I ADD SOMETHING HERE??}}}}),
  list(width = 0.01, item = "vline", hjust = 0.5),
  list(width = 0.05, display = ~n, hjust = 0.5, heading 
= "N"),
  list(width = 0.01, item = "vline", hjust = 0.5),
  list(width = 0.05, display = ~n_events, width = 0.05, 
hjust = 0.5, heading = "Events"),
  list(width = 0.1, item = "vline", hjust = 0.5),
  list(width = 0.55, item = "forest", hjust = 0.5, 
heading = "HR (95% CI)", linetype = "dashed",
       line_x = 0),
  list(width = 0.03, item = "vline", hjust = 1),
  list(width = 0.05, heading = "HR (95% CI)", hjust = 
0.5,
   display = ~ifelse(reference, "Reference", 
sprintf("%0.2f (%0.2f, %0.2f)",

trans(estimate), trans(conf.low), trans(conf.high))), 
display_na = NA),
  list(width = 0.01, item = "vline", hjust = 1),
  list(width = 0.03,
       display = ~ifelse(reference, "", 
format.pval(p.value, digits = 3, eps = 0.001)),
       display_na = NA, hjust = 0.5, heading = "P")
)
```

Comment: You could wrap the values in the data frame before running the model: Something like `library(stringr); data$long_names = str_wrap(data$long_names, 10)`. If the factor order is important, then the following will do the same as above, but will maintain the column as factor class: `library(forcats); data$long_names = fct_relabel(data$long_names, function(x) str_wrap(x, 10))`

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you